# Snyc Azure local Tables with Azure Server tables in xamarin forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using following method to sync Azure DB local table with server table but the changes which I made on my local DB are not reflecting to the Azure server,

```
public async Task PushDataAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _mobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                 throw exc;
            }
         }
```

While using above method I am getting Error :-
Push Operation Fail.

Any Help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are using right method to sync your offline store with server which is :-

```
 await _mobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

I would suggest you to wrote few line of code in catch block which will help you to find out the reasons why the operations are not performed on server side
please use code bellow in catch block:-

```
public async Task PushDataAsync()
        {
          try
            {
                await _mobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            }
            catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
            {
                if (exc.PushResult != null)
                {
                    syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
                }
            }

            // Simple error/conflict handling.
            if (syncErrors != null)
            {
                foreach (var error in syncErrors)
                {
                    if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null || error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Insert && error.Result != null || error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Delete && error.Result != null)
                    {
                        //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                        await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(error.Result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Discard local change.
                        await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
                    }


                        Debug.WriteLine(@"Error executing sync {2} operation. Item: {0} ({1}). Operation discarded.",
                            error.TableName, error.Item["id"], error.OperationKind);

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Above method will defiantly save/Update your pending offline table operations to the Azure server , in queue fashion ...,
 
Try to find the errors in output window from visual studio View --> Output 
or hit ctrl + w, o as short cut key in visual studio

Comment: above method is correct it works properly using just need to add reference azure mobile service

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PushAsync() pushes ALL changes from your local store to the cloud and that PullAsync first performs a Push. I would get rid of the service variable for each table and just use the service as a singleton class across your app. Here is my initialization. After this method returns, my local db is synced with the cloud and I can start using my tables:

```
 public async Task InitializeStoreAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var sqliteStore = _platform.MobileServiceSqliteStore;

        sqliteStore.DefineTable<Memory>();
        sqliteStore.DefineTable<User> ();
        sqliteStore.DefineTable<Comment> ();
        sqliteStore.DefineTable<Status>();

        await _zumoClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(sqliteStore);
        _memoryTable = _zumoClient.GetSyncTable<Memory> ();
        _userTable = _zumoClient.GetSyncTable<User> ();
        _commentTable = _zumoClient.GetSyncTable<Comment> ();
        _statusTable = _zumoClient.GetSyncTable<Status>();

        await _userTable.PullAsync ();
        await _memoryTable.PullAsync ();
        await _commentTable.PullAsync ();
        await _statusTable.PullAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine ("Initialize Store failed: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/ search for "Handling Conflict Resolution"